# Can't override method C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm solving the 8 Queens Puzzle (place 8 queens on chessboard without conflicts) and created a class `Square`.  Now I think this class should be the father of 2 subclasses `Queen` and `Empty`.

There is an other class:  `Chessboard` that contains a bi-directional arrays, what I want is that when printing I will have 8 `Q` (Queens) and 56 `E` (empty see code).

These are the classes (I'll not write all):

```
class Square{
    int x;
    int y;
public :
Square() {};
Square(int ,int);
bool isAvaible();
void swapStatus();
virtual void printValue();
void setCoord(int,int);
int getX();
int getY();
};
void Square::printValue(){
    std::cout << "S ";
};
```

---

```
#include "square.hpp"

class Queen : public Square{
public:
    ...
    virtual void printValue();
    ...
};
void Queen::printValue(){
    std::cout << "Q ";
}
```

---

```
#include "Square.hpp"

class Empty : Square {
public:
    ...
    virtual void printValue();
    ...
};
void Empty::printValue(){
    std::cout << "E ";
}
```

At the beginning all elements inside `Chessboard` are `Square`, when a queen is added the `Square` must be replaced by the `Queen`.
This is how I do it :

```
...
std::vector<std::vector<Square> > squares;
...

void Chessboard::setQueen(int x, int y){
    squares[x][y]=Queen(x,y);
}
```

I use this method to set 8 queen on the chessboard and when printing all squares this is the output :

```
S S S S S S S S 
S S S S S S S S 
S S S S S S S S 
S S S S S S S S 
S S S S S S S S 
S S S S S S S S 
S S S S S S S S 
S S S S S S S S
```

Instead of :

```
Q S S S S S S S 
S Q S S S S S S 
S S Q S S S S S 
S S S Q S S S S 
S S S S Q S S S 
S S S S S Q S S 
S S S S S S Q S 
S S S S S S S Q
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: See [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).

Answer (score 3):

Your `squares` vector (why a 2D `vector`? A fixed 2D array would make more sense) contains actual `Square` objects. As such, you *can't* store any `Queen` or `Empty` objects in it, as they would [get sliced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/), which is what you are seeing happen.

You need to instead store `Square*` pointers in your `squares` vector.

For instance, you could create a separate array/vector of 8 `Queen` objects and 56 `Empty` objects, and then store `Square*` pointers to those objects in your `squares`, eg:

```cpp
...
std::vector<std::vector<Square*> > squares; // or: Square* squares[8][8];
Queen queens[8];
int q_index = 0;
...

void Chessboard::setQueen(int x, int y){
    if (q_index < 8) {
        squares[x][y] = &queens[q_index++];
        squares[x][y]->setCoord(x, y);
    }
}
```

Or alternatively, just dynamically create all of your `squares` objects using `new` (preferably wrapped in `std::unique_ptr`), eg:

```cpp
...
std::vector<std::vector<Square*> > squares; // or: Square* squares[8][8];
...

void Chessboard::setQueen(int x, int y){
    delete squares[x][y];
    squares[x][y] = new Queen(x, y);
}
```

```cpp
...
std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Square>>> squares; // or: std::unique_ptr<Square> squares[8][8];
...

void Chessboard::setQueen(int x, int y){
    squares[x][y] = std::make_unique<Queen>(x, y);
}
```

Comment: Ok I didn't know about slicing, so the queen's function is lost because squares can contain only Square. I never used smart pointers but used some pointers in C (I'm new). If I understand what you're suggesting nothing has to change, just use pointers instead of objects and this is the trick right?

Comment: Well, managing those pointers *correctly* can be tricky, in of itself. But yes, you need to use pointers (or references, but you can't have a vector of references) in order for virtual function calls to work.

Comment: I'm sure it is...But this is the generic idea ok perfect thanks I will study these smart pointers. Do you now any website that explain it well?

Comment: @FinleyAdams This is the best source of information: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr
It may contain a lot of text - just read slowly, it explains everything you need.

Comment: @alexpanter You're very welcome!